# unity 3d remote and c# error?

Tags: c#, android

I want to simulate unity 3d remote and c# script to test touch response.

In my android device and I am getting error on playing `the referenced script on this is behaviour is missing`.

Please solve this problem.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TouchSripts : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void OnGui()
    {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            string message = "";
            message += "ID: " + touch.fingerId + "\n";

            message += "phase :" + touch.phase.ToString() + "\n";
            message += "TapCount:" + touch.tapCount + "\n";
            message += "Pos x :" + touch.position.x + "\n";
            message += "Pos y:" + touch.position.y+ "\n";

            int num = touch.fingerId;
            GUI.Label(new Rect(0 + 130 * num, 0, 120, 100) ,message);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {    
    }

}
```

Comment: You may be interested to check out the game dev specific StackExchange community: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This error is called when Unity can not access a script, usually because names are not matching up. So simply make sure your script inside the project window is the same as your class name (TouchSripts). Sometimes that doesn't correctly fix it so just Select All and Copy the script, go back into unity, delete the old script, create a new script (making sure to call it TouchSripts), and delete the content of the new script, and paste your script into it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You probably mistyped a reference somewhere in your scripts. It's also possible you forgot to assign something in the inspector. This is not an unity remote issue, you should get the same error when testing in the Editor